# Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at eval (“script-src”)

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, content-security-policy, helmet.js

Hello Everyone I just deployed a full stack vuejs and express application to heroku. This is my backend code serving the vue js application.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/dist/"));
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/dist/index.html");
  });
}
```

When I visit my applicaiton and try and login I get this error.

Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at eval (“script-src”).

Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://localhost:3000/api/v1/user/login (“default-src”). xhr.js:177:12

can someone please help me fix this issue. Thanks

Comment: Are you using helmet as part of your express stack?

Comment: The localhost:3000 looks suspicious. If its hosted on heroku why would it be localhost:3000? Do you have a url hard coded somewhere?

Comment: @Joe yes I have helmet js added to my express application could that be causing the problem?

Comment: @RobLouie localhost on heroku should just translate to my url if im not mistaken

Comment: What version of Vue?  I know 2.x has issues with CSPs (like Helmet defines) depending on how they are configured.

Comment: @Joe the current version of vue im using is number 3

Comment: @Joe i removed helmet js and it works but now im getting cors errors lol so ill have to fix that then

Comment: You should use `helmet` - you can fix up the CSP.  This was true in v2 not sure about v3: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#CSP-environments

Comment: @Joe now im having issues with socket io running on heroku the rooms are not recieving messages brodcasted